# Magento Paid user registration for Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, frontend, customer-group

I have different types of C**ustomer group (General, School, Publisher, Corporate).** Customer select our Customer group on registration page from frontend.

But I need charge some amount ($100) when customer register as **Publisher**.

Please give any suggestion that how to implement.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I have not found any solution. Please share any solution if you have. Thanks for reply

Comment: Can you provide the exact desired workflow. In example, when and where  should a customer enter payment. Ideally it should be a product.    Let me know and I'll take a try.

Comment: Please check http://gobookkart.com/customer/account/create/. Here I have 4 types customer group(General,School,Publisher,Corporate). When customer select group "Publisher", then I want to charge "INR 2000".  

When Customer click on "Pay Now INR 2000" button. Customer registered with status "deactive". When Payment Successfully, change status "Active". 

Its display in customer account section also.

Comment: How you implement this feature?I also want to implement it in my store.Can you please add your answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below steps:-

Check all the shopping cart price rules -

```
Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules
```

that are conditioned by shipping and payment methods (under the Conditions tab). 
Inside those rules check the customer groups for which they can apply.

Comment: I am not want discount coupon code. But want payment on registration page.

Like:  http://www.example.com/index.php/customer/account/create/

Comment: I want Registration Fee. 

http://gobookkart.com/customer/account/create/

Please check above link. 

I have created four types group (General, School, Publisher and Corporate). When customer select Publisher, I want registration fee ($40). Only for Publisher.